# Do I need to set seed in all modules where I import numpy or tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to produce reproducible results while training a deep learning model using `keras` with `tensorflow` as backend.

I went through this document: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development to set numpy's, python's and tf's random seed in the `train.py` file which I use for training.

Now, this file imports some functions from two other modules `utils.py` and `model.py`. In both these files, I have `import numpy as np` and `import tensorflow as tf` at the top. My question is - how does importing from different modules and setting random seeds work?

a) Do I need to set random seed in each file after the import statement?

b) Or, do I just need to set these seeds in the `train.py` and do all the imports from other modules after these setting seeds commands?

c) Does `tf.set_random_seed(1)` needs to be done after `import tensorflow as tf` also?

d) Do I need to set `tf.set_random_seed(1)` even if I am not importing tensorflow or keras and just importing layers from keras?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, use the tensorflow.keras instead of keras.

Usually, it suffices to use the seed in the main script in the following manner.

```
import random
random.seed(1)
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1)
```

But, if you have multiple modules and they have some randomized operation (such as weight initialization), then add these lines to each of your module.

Additionally, these only don't guarantee 100% reproducibility, if you are using a GPU, there maybe some randomness due to that too.

You can use https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism

`os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'` For tensorflow==2.1.0

For tensorflow < 2.1

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tfdeterminism import patch
patch()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so does `os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'` For tensorflow==2.1.0, replace the usage of CPU? Because I currently have a similar problem where my results aren't being the same and read some other posts and they all suggested using the CPU rather than the GPU. Has this issue been solved in TensorFlow 2.1?

Comment: No, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/34887/files (it makes cuDNN algo deterministic) as you can see it's from NVIDIA, it's actually for GPU. You should look into the https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism repo, they discuss the GPU determinism. But still there can be some probabilistic factors in the trainng process.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided. Hence, the only way to get reproducibility in Keras + TensorFlow is by using the CPU instead of the GPU?

Comment: Yes, in that case, CPU reprodibility is guranteed. But, GPU can have minor issues.