# Does setting the seed in tf.random.set_seed also set the seed used by the glorot_uniform kernel_initializer when using a conv2D layer in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, random-seed, reproducible-research

I'm currently training a `convolutional neural network` using a `conv2D layer` defined like this:

```
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='SAME', activation='relu')(inputs)
```

My understanding is that the default kernel_initializer is `glorot_uniform` which has a default seed of 'none':

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format=None,
        dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True,
        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros',
        kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
        kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs
    )



tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

I'm trying to produce reproducible code and have already set random seeds as per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290368/typeerror-session-object-is-not-callable-error-running-sess-tf-compat-v1):

```
seed_num = 1

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
np.random.seed(seed_num)
rn.seed(seed_num)

session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

Is the `tf.random.set_seed` seed number used by `glorot_uniform` within a `conv2D layer`? If not, how would that seed be defined when defining the `conv2D layer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each layer, you can use the seed for kernel and bias initializers.

You can seed your initializer separately,

`kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0))`

From documentation:

```
glorot_normal

keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None)

Glorot normal initializer, also called Xavier normal initializer.

It draws samples from a truncated normal distribution centered on 0 with stddev = sqrt(2 / (fan_in + fan_out)) where fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor and fan_out is the number of output units in the weight tensor.

Arguments

    seed: A Python integer. Used to seed the random generator.
```

Comment: Thanks. So I just need to run that once at the top of the file and then everytime I define a Conv2D layer it will use that seed with that initializer by default?

Comment: Yes, you can create an initializer variable with a seed and repeatedly use in all of your layers, also if you use tensorflow seed, it by default seeds everything with the seed provided by you. For a more robust reproducibility you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910157/do-i-need-to-set-seed-in-all-modules-where-i-import-numpy-or-tensorflow/60911053#60911053

Comment: So I don't need to do anything differently in the Conv2D line of code? Or do I need to specify `kernel_initializer=my_kernel_initializer` in the Conv2D parameters (after defining `my_kernel_initializer` as `my_kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)`)?

Comment: set_seed is enough https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

Comment: So I don't need to run `kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)` at all because I've already set `tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)`? Sorry, I'm confused as to whether setting tf.random.set_seed is enough or whether I also need to define `kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=seed_num)` as well?

Comment: both are okay, depends on your reproducibility level. as you can see in the documentation. Its interactions with operation-level seeds is as follows:
If the operation seed is not set but the global seed is set: The system picks an operation seed from a stream of seeds determined by the global seed.

Comment: In simple words, if you use same steps to train a model and save weights, the set_seed is enough if that's what you want.

Comment: So the answer to my question (Does setting the seed in tf.random.set_seed also set the seed used by the glorot_uniform kernel_initializer when using a conv2D layer in keras?) is "yes", and therefore nothing further is required?

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to [Zabir Al Nazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4622046/zabir-al-nazi), the answer is "yes". Setting `tf.random.set_seed()` also sets the `Conv2D` layer's `glorot_uniform` seed.

Comment: if the answer helps don't hesitate to upvote/accept :)